# Generate fields in content from other content values?

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I want to generate fields in a content from the values of other content.

Specifically, I have a list of "players" stored as a content type, and a separate content type called "Events". Events list the rank of each player that participated. On the "player" content, I'd like to be able to display the players wins by searching all the "events" content. Is this possible?

Also, in Views, is it possible to generate a list of all the events a player has won, as well as how many?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Yes it is possible with views "**Advanced > Contextual Filters**". Before that you have to Create a Relationship ("**Advanced > Relationships**") with the field of the event that contains the Player information.

2) In this case you have to set the "**Advanced > Use aggregation:Yes**" and then use the "Count (Distinct)" aggregation in any field in the results.

If your **Drupal level is not too high with views module** better start with some learning tutorials like these from here: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5684/where-can-i-find-a-good-tutorial-on-drupal-7-views

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help! When im trying to create the relationship, I cannot seem to find where I can set the field of the event containing the player who won.

Comment: You have to add the relationship field (Events <-> Players) on the content type (only one of them). You can use modules like [Entity Relationship](http://drupal.org/project/er).